# Eloquent save database laravel when using Class Threads multi threading, blank space result

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel, eloquent, pthreads

i have a trouble using multi threading php, my code like this

namespace Automation\Threads;

```
use DB, Crypt, App;
use Thread;

use Automation\Models\UserLog;

class myThread extends Thread {

        public function __construct($arg) {
            $this->arg = $arg;
        }

        public function run() {
            if ($this->arg) {
                $sleep = mt_rand(1, 10);
                echo $this->arg." start : ".date("g:i:sa").Thread::getCurrentThreadId()."<br>";
                sleep($sleep);

                echo $this->arg." end : ".date("g:i:sa")."<br>";

                //if added this code, this thread not gonna work
                $userlog= new UserLog;
                $userlog->user = "some user do something";
                $userlog->save();
            }
        }
}
```

it makes an empty or blank space, withouth data userlog added. it did work if i wasnt use laravel eloquent DB save, can be done with just php normal save. any one know why it happens ??

[another code]

it happens too when i am using pheanstalk on laravel on ubuntu linux the error says

```
[PDOException]         
  could not find driver
```

it appears when on listen queue on command terminal

Comment: Without diving in I would suggest You to use `queue` and put some time consuming tasks there. Multi threading is a complicated solution which I do not recommend to use.

Comment: hmm i dont know if queue laravel can do task paralel massively, i think queue is just single / serial task to do in, fifo (first in first out) . Code above is just for example. i planned to use multithreading for massive data / task @GiedriusKiršys